# Injection and lose of fluid injected and pressure drop down?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, petroleum-engineering, injection

I am trying to develop a field by using water injection.

I am facing a problem that the average reservoir pressure is dropping down and the BHP of the production wells dropping down as well until it reach the limit and stop producing.

Therefore, my injection is not achieving its purpose by maintaining the reservoir pressure and the production. The injectors are in the layers 4, 5 , 6 , 7 and 8 While producers are in the layers 1, 2 and 3 Would you please suggest to me how can i maintain the pressure and the production

Comment: There seems to be a lot of information missing from this question. I'm not even close to the relevant field, and I can guess that more information about the layers and configuration would be required to even start an answer.

Comment: What kind of information?

Comment: Well, just start with where is the reservoir ? above by how many metres as that will have a pressure, or below by how many metres as that will then need power to bring the fluid up... A diagram of what you are talking about in terms of layers would help... How thick are the layers... Voted to close as unclear...

Comment: Try the SPE ; they have books, courses, and maybe a chat room. I would be amazed if you got any useful information here.

Comment: This question has been cross posted at SE Earth Science.

Comment: @Fred I did posted there first before I know there is a petroleum engineering stack exchange. I hope this didnt trouble you?

Comment: @SolarMike Thank you very much for your reply,

Comment: @blacksmith37 thank you for your comment but where can i find SPE chat room?